# Python Reddit bot not correctly encoding special characters

Tags: python, bots, reddit

I have a Reddit bot that tries to convert ASCII text to images. I'm running into issues encoding special characters, as per [this issue](https://github.com/itsmichaelwang/mobile-wizard/issues/2).

I have a [repo](https://github.com/itsmichaelwang/mobile-wizard/) dedicated to this project, but for the sake of brevity, I'll post the relevant code. I tried switching to Python 3 (since I heard it handles Unicode more elegantly than Python 2), but that didn't solve the issue.

This function pulls comments from Reddit. As you can see, I'm encoding everything in utf-8 as soon as I pull it, which is why I'm confused.

```
def comments_by_keyword(r, keyword, subreddit='all', print_comments=False):
    """Fetches comments from a subreddit containing a given keyword or phrase
    Args:
        r: The praw.Reddit class, which is required to access the Reddit API
        keyword: Keep only the comments that contain the keyword or phrase
        subreddit: A string denoting the subreddit(s) to look through, default is 'all' for r/all
        limit: The maximum number of posts to fetch, increase for more thoroughness at the cost of increased redundancy/running time
        print_comments: (Debug option) If True, comments_by_keyword will print every comment it fetches, instead of just returning filtered ones
    Returns:
        An array of comment objects whose body text contains the given keyword or phrase
    """

    output = []
    comments = r.get_comments(subreddit, limit=1000)

    for comment in comments:
        # ignore the case of the keyword and comments being fetched
        # Example: for keyword='RIP mobile users', comments_by_keyword would keep 'rip Mobile Users', 'rip MOBILE USERS', etc.
        if keyword.lower() in comment.body.lower():
            print(comment.body.encode('utf-8'))
            print("=====\n")
            output.append(comment)
        elif print_comments:
            print(comment.body.encode('utf-8'))
            print("=====\n")
    return output
```

And then this converts it to an image:

```
def str_to_img(str, debug=False):
    """Converts a given string to a PNG image, and saves it to the return variable"""
    # use 12pt Courier New for ASCII art
    font = ImageFont.truetype("cour.ttf", 12)

    # do some string preprocessing
    str = str.replace("\n\n", "\n") # Reddit requires double newline for new line, don't let the bot do this
    str = html.unescape(str)

    img = Image.new('RGB', (1,1))
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    str_by_line = str.split("\n")
    num_of_lines = len(str_by_line)

    line_widths = []
    for i, line in enumerate(str_by_line):
        line_widths.append(d.textsize(str_by_line[i], font=font)[0])
    line_height = d.textsize(str, font=font)[1]     # the height of a line of text should be unchanging

    img_width = max(line_widths)                                    # the image width is the largest of the individual line widths
    img_height = num_of_lines * line_height             # the image height is the # of lines * line height

    # creating the output image
    # add 5 pixels to account for lowercase letters that might otherwise get truncated
    img = Image.new('RGB', (img_width, img_height + 5), 'white')
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    for i, line in enumerate(str_by_line):
        d.text((0,i*line_height), line, font=font, fill='black')
    output = BytesIO()

    if (debug):
        img.save('test.png', 'PNG')
    else:
        img.save(output, 'PNG')

    return output
```

Like I said, I'm encoding everything in utf-8, but the special characters don't show up properly. I'm also using Courier New from the official .ttf file, which is suppose to support a wide base of characters and symbols, so I'm not sure what the issue is there either.

I feel like it's something obvious. Can anyone enlighten me? It's not ImageDraw, is it? To top it all off, it seems like text encoding as a whole is sort of ambiguous, so even after reading other StackOverflow posts (and blog posts about encoding), I'm hardly closer to a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run any tests myself currently and I can't leave a comment due to low rep so I'm dropping a partial answer that hopefully gives some ideas what to try. I'm also a bit rusty with Python 2 but lets try..

So two things. First:

> I'm encoding everything in utf-8 as soon as I pull it

Are you?

```
print(comment.body.encode('utf-8'))
print("=====\n")
output.append(comment)
```

You're encoding the print output, but appending the original comment to the output list as it was outputted by praw. Does praw output unicode objects?

Because I would imagine unicode objects are what the ImageDraw module wants. Looking at its source code it doesn't seem to have any clue about the encoding of the text you're trying to render. Meaning Python 2 strings would be rendered probably as single byte characters leading to garbage in the output in case of utf8 encoding.

http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.truetype mentions "encoding" parameter, which should default to **unic**ode. Could be worth to try setting it just in case. Maybe it raises an error if the font is not unicode compatible.

Encodings in Python 2 aren't fun. But one thing I would still try to make sure that unicode object is passed to the ImageDraw (try unicode(str) or str.decode("utf8"))